# Extracting ground-truth clusters from stochastic block model generated using igraph

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, igraph

I generate a graph using `sample_sbm` with 100 nodes and 2 clusters and intra-cluster edge probability greater than inter-cluster edge probability. That is, I tell `sample_sbm` to generate a graph with two clusters by passing a 2-by-2 matrix into the `pref.matrix` parameter. My resulting graph looks like this:

[image]

Is there some way to recover the ground-truth clusters? It seems using `cluster_leading_eigen` works, but if I can recover the information used to generate the network in the first place, i.e., the exact membership, that would be best. I tried searching the documentation but had trouble finding what I needed. I'm working with larger networks with more clusters as well, so any way to recover this information efficiently would be fantastic!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered by Vincent Traag when I asked on the igraph forum. Based on the documentation for [C](https://igraph.org/c/doc/igraph-Generators.html#igraph_sbm_game) and [Python](https://igraph.org/python/doc/igraph.GraphBase-class.html#SBM), it seems the clusters are assigned in consecutive order to the vertices.